# Windows Forms unhandled error pop up message

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, unhandled-exception, .net-3.5

I have a windows forms application (.NET C# 3.5)... that is throwing an error.. but I have 2 scenarios:

Client: on the client side.. the error is logged into a log.txt file.. AND an error pop up message appears

> See the end of this message for details on invoking just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.
>
> ************** Exception Text **************
>   System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Internal.IntUnsafeNativeMethods.IntSaveDC(HandleRef hDC)
>
> ...

Local: in my local computer... when the application throws the error, it is logged to the log.txt file.. but I DON'T see any pop up message...

so.. I was wondering, if maybe I have some Windows option to: NOT THROW unhandled errors ?

Note: I don't think it is something in the application, because the build is exactly the same version. so it must be something in the environment.

Comment: The title says `Windows Forms` but the there is an `asp.net` tag.  Did you really mean `Web Forms` instead of `Windows Forms`?

Comment: oops sorry.. I've used a lot of asp.net recently... removing that tag.
Actually I mean Windows forms... I've added "asp.net" to the tags "accidentally"

Comment: What exactly occurs when the application throws the error on your local system...you said it logs, and does not show a popup...does the process end? Does it hang? Does it continue?

Answer (score 0):

There was a change in how unhandled exceptions were treated on threads between v1.1 and v2.0 of .Net. It sounds like on your machine, the v1.1 model is being used, where the exception is swallowed. Do you have the tag `<legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy enabled='1'/>` in your machine.config or app.config file?

Comment: @jrista in my local, the application continues...
@codekaizen the app.config is the same in both, client and my local.. and there isn't any legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy... the machine.config applies to winforms?

thanks for your help

Comment: @user - the machine.config file applies to _everything_ in .Net on that machine.

Comment: oh ok, well, I have checked the machine.config and there isn't any "legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy"...  
This error starts becoming even worst... I could replicate the pop up message...but the second time I try to do it... didn't work... I have tried like 5 more times... and I CAN'T get the error message again :s

Comment: Do you have an event handler attached to `AppDomain.Current.UnhandledException`?

Comment: Actually I've just added the code to catch the unhandled error... the weird thing is why in the client the same application same version same configurations... is throwing me an error that is not happening in my dev computer... anyway as you say, with the AppDomain.Current.UnhandledException I should be able to catch any error... Thanks...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.setunhandledexceptionmode.aspx